# How can I replace these characters in the parentheses: ( { } " " \ ) from my stringified Json object with nothing

Tags: javascript, json, web

So I'm making a little game guide for a project(tft). 
https://chrissawma.github.io/TftGuide/ 
The problem is that I have a function in my code that makes a div element where the Json object is stringyfied then passed on to the innerHTML, everytime I click on it even though I tried using the '.replace' method using RegEx for special characters mentioned. (the curly braces, the left slash, and quotes). I just want a neat little caption for each description of the 'hero types' on the left column. 
 //Sorry for the dumb var names.. was in a hurry.

PS. only the top 4 (symbols of types of heros) are enabled to work, so that's where I'm testing it and I've disabled the rest. 
Please play around and see what I did wrong. Thanks guys 
--- a young grunt.

Ive tried a lot of ways but I think i've failed to implement them correctly. If anyone can show me 1 way or another to do it. I'm grateful.

```
function originStat(hero, list, properti, x) {
    var list = originList;
    var genre = list[hero];
    var target = genre[properti];


    for(let obs in list) { 
      var x = x;
      if (x === undefined){
              x = 0;  } 
      final = JSON.stringify(target[x]);
  }
            var statsheet = document.createElement('div');
            var dad = document.getElementsByClassName('heroes')[1];

              statsheet.setAttribute('class', 'assassin-stats');
              statsheet.style.opacity = 1;
              // lasttoken is the string form of the object returned.
              var lasttoken = JSON.stringify(final);
                    var unwant; //unwanted strings
                    lasttoken.replace(/\{/, "");  
                    lasttoken.replace(/\}/, "");
                    lasttoken.replace(/\"/, "");
                    const actuallylasttoken= lasttoken;

                  statsheet.innerHTML = actuallylasttoken;
                  dad.appendChild(statsheet);
                  return (statsheet.innerHTML);

  }
```

actual erroneous result I'm getting:
"{\"needed\":3,\"effect\":\"At the start of combat, summon an Elemental. Elemental has 2200 health and 100 Attack Damage.\"}"

what I need: 
needed:3 
effect:At the start of combat, summon an Elemental. 
Elemental has 2200 health and 100 Attack Damage.
OR 
needed:3 effect:At the start of combat, summon an Elemental. Elemental has 2200 health and 100 Attack Damage.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```js
var lasttoken = JSON.stringify(final);
var unwant; //unwanted strings
lasttoken.replace(/\{/, "");
lasttoken.replace(/\}/, "");
lasttoken.replace(/\"/, "");
const actuallylasttoken= lasttoken;
```

The regexes(`/\{/` etc.) doesn't have global flag `g`, so it will only match the first match, and thus will only remove the first occurrence of the character.

You can fix it by adding `g` to each regex.

```js
var lasttoken = JSON.stringify(final);
var unwant; //unwanted strings
lasttoken.replace(/\{/g, "");
lasttoken.replace(/\}/g, "");
lasttoken.replace(/\"/g, "");
const actuallylasttoken= lasttoken;
```

Notice the `g` after the second `/` in each regex. Now, it matches all occurrences of the character, and should successfully remove the unwanted characters.

Also, since you are doing the same thing to each character, you can condense it to one regex by using a set.

The characters would be wrapped by `[]`, which will then match for any one character in the set. So, `/[ag0]/g` matches all occurrences of characters `a`, `g`, and `0`. Now, applying it to your case:

```js
var lasttoken = JSON.stringify(final);
var unwant; //unwanted strings
lasttoken.replace(/[\{\}\"]/g, "");
const actuallylasttoken= lasttoken;
```

So, regex `/[\{\}\"]/g` matches for all `{`, `}`, or `"`. Then, each of them is replaced by empty string, removing them.

Then, you would need to assign this to `lasttoken`, as `.replace()` will not modify the variable.

```js
var lasttoken = JSON.stringify(final);
var unwant; //unwanted strings
lasttoken = lasttoken.replace(/[\{\}\"]/g, "");
const actuallylasttoken= lasttoken;
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: Also, you would need to assign the modified value to `lasttoken`. My bad. Fixed.